# Nested zooms issue in D3

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Please see my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/haiphong/BRjFE/

You can hold SHIFT and then drag and drop the rectangle to move it and the circle inside it around. You can hold SHIFT and zoom as well. This zoom/pan is done by `d3.behavior.zoom()`. Works well.

I want to zoom and pan the circle when NOT holding shift. So, I create another `d3.behavior.zoom()`.  However, the circle can be zoomed but not panned. By debugging, I see that when I pan the circle, the handling code doesn't execute.

In sum, when binding a `zoom` to both the outer `g` element and the inner `g` element, the outer works well for zoom/pan; however, the inner only works for zoom. How to get it work for pan as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for my answer. http://jsfiddle.net/haiphong/BRjFE/4/

When I pan the circle, its `zoom` event doesn't fire. However, its `zoomstart` event fires and it is fired before its parent's `zoomstart`. Somehow, when the parent's `zoomstart` fires, it eats the circle's event.

So, in the `zoomstart` of the circle, I force the event stop propagating when SHIFT isn't being hold. That makes the circle `zoom` fires.